# Is there any way to add KDE widgets in unity environment?

Tags: unity, 12.10, kubuntu, kde

I need a KDE plasma desktop widget (for typing quick short notes). But I use unity environment. Is there any way to add KDE widgets in unity environment? Or is there any widget or widget manager for ubuntu (unity) desktop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a widget manager for GNOME/Unity called [gDesklets](http://www.gdesklets.de/), but it doesn't appear to have a note typing widget.

However, If you simply want a note typing program, you could try [Tomboy Notes](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/tomboy/):

[image: Screenshot]

You can make the windows stay on top of other windows by right clicking on the title bar and selecting `Always on Top`, so you can have your notes open on top of your work:

[image: Menu]